# How to map to Sitecore Rules Field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, tds

I'm having some trouble mapping to a `Rules` data field in Sitecore.  I've got a rendering parameters template that has a data field named "Redirect Rules."

I'm using TDS and Glass to map the objects back to Sitecore.  In the generated class, I get the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// The Redirect Rule field.
/// <para></para>
/// <para>Field Type: Rules</para>      
/// <para>Field ID: 659373d6-c5c5-4851-aa1f-066f53218780</para>
/// <para>Custom Data: </para>
/// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]
    [SitecoreField(IMy_Name_Rendering_ParametersConstants.Redirect_RuleFieldName)]
    public virtual object /* UNKNOWN */ Redirect_Rule  {get; set;}
```

When I attempt to get the value of the "Redirect Rules" field in my view rendering via

```
GetRenderingParameters<My_Name_Rendering_Parameters>();
```

the "Redirect Rules"property is null.  I have verified that the field is populated with rules by examining it in the Experience Editor.

Any clue to what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craig. Look here for a modified T4 template that maps the Rules field to a string value: https://gist.github.com/patrickperrone/9626cccbd044cc418539

Here is my [blog post](http://sitecoreblog.patrickperrone.com/2015/04/how-to-map-sitecore-rules-field-with.html) that covers this in a little more detail.

Excerpted from my post:

> The basic issue is that the glassv3item.tt template doesn't know how
>   to deal with the `Rules` field. The `GetGlassFieldByType` method is
>   responsible for assigning a type to mapped field. It does this with a
>   `switch` statement. Our rules field is falling all the way through to
>   the `default` case which maps the field to an `object`. We need to add a
>   case for the `field.Type` value when it equals "rules".

Short answer: I use a `string` type as my mapped `field.Type` when value equals "rules".

You can see this for yourself on lines 246-247 [here](https://gist.github.com/patrickperrone/9626cccbd044cc418539).

Comment: Could you add the details/exploitation into your answer here please